# Is it possible to use multiple left join in Confluent KSQL query? tried to join stream with more than 1 tables , if not then whats the solution?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Stream :

```
describe ammas;

 Field   | Type                        
-------------------------------------  
 ROWTIME | BIGINT           (system)  
 ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)   
 ID      | INTEGER                      
 -------------------------------------
```

For runtime statistics and query details run: `DESCRIBE EXTENDED <Stream,Table>;`

Table-01 :

```
ksql> show tables;

Table Name | Kafka Topic | Format    | Windowed 
-------------------------------------------------
ANNAT      | anna        | DELIMITED | false    
APPAT      | appa        | DELIMITED | false    
-------------------------------------------------
```

Trying to Join stream vs. table-01 is working as expected. 
Create stream finalstream as select `a.id` from `ammas` a left join `appat b` on `a.id = b.id` where `b.id` is `null`.

But when I tried to join more than one table with stream based on the following query:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM ammas cd LEFT JOIN appat ab ON ab.id = cd.id LEFT JOIN annat aa ON aa.id =cd.id;
ServerError:io.confluent.ksql.parser.exception.ParseFailedException
Caused by: null
```

What is going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Based on my analysis:  multiple joins in a single statement is currently not supported. you can accomplish the same thing by writing multiple KSQL statements:CREATE STREAM intermediate AS SELECT * FROM ammas cd LEFT JOIN appat ab ON ab.id = cd.id  SELECT * FROM intermediate cd LEFT JOIN annat aa ON aa.id=cd.id

Answer (score 1):

KSQL currently (v5.3) only supports a single join operation per statement. If you want to perform multiple joins you have to "daisy-chain" them in multiple statements, e.g.

```
CREATE STREAM out1 AS 
  SELECT * FROM ammas cd 
           LEFT JOIN appat ab 
             ON ab.id = cd.id 

CREATE STREAM out_final AS 
  SELECT * FROM out1 o 
           LEFT JOIN annat aa ON o.id =cd.id;
```

---

*Update November 2020: ksqlDB supports multi-way joins were added in ksqlDB v0.9. Confluent Platform 6.0 includes ksqlDB 0.10.2 and therefore also includes this functionality. See the [release blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksqldb-0-9-0-feature-updates/) and [documentation](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/join-streams-and-tables/#n-way-joins) for details.*

Comment: Is this still true with v0.13.0? It seems like that...

Comment: thanks. I was on the wrong track anyway, seem to have rather a connect than a KSQL problem...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple join having stream and tables is supported in the actual version (Confluent Platform 7.x at the moment I'm writing)

Please see this document
https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/multi-joins/ksql.html

The example is with 1 stream and 2 tables
Currently I don't know if it's supported with 3 or more tables

The important thing is that the join with the right side must be with its primary key